# How to convert/cut uint256_t to uint8_t[ ]

Tags: c++

I got one library that uses `uint256_t` to represent a hash, and another library that uses `uint8_t` array for this.

I guess there should be a way to cut/convert this `uint256_t` into an `uint8_t[32]` somehow.

However, I couldn't find yet how that could be easily converted.

Comment: Assuming endianness is not a problem, `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&value)` should be enough.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's UB. I would suggest using `std::memcpy` instead.

Comment: @Resurrection It's not UB if `uint8_t` is a `char` typedef. One could `static_assert` that first. However, indeed [`std::bit_cast<>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) or prior to C++20 the `std::memcpy()` version are definitely defined and preferable generally - and should get optimised into the same code anyway.

Comment: @underscore_d, and what if `static_assert` fails?

Comment: @Evg Let's be honest, chances of it not being an `unsigned char` typedef are virtually zero. If it fails, you go and fix the code.

Comment: @Evg Then do it the other way...? I only mentioned how to make sure the `reinterpret_cast` is valid before doing it. I would prefer it not be done that way, as I also said already.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, or the compiler. :)

Comment: which compiler supports `uint256_t` ?

Comment: the library adds it.

Comment: @M.M • clang 11 supports 256-bit integers.

Comment: @user2524707 `uintNN_t` names are reserved for the implementation; libraries can't add them (without causing undefined behaviour, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).

You have two unrelated types, but you know that the binary representation of the hash is identical for both. The safest way to convert between the two is via `memcpy`.

```
uint256_t source_hash;
// compute source_hash
// [...]

uint8_t dest_hash[32];
std::memcpy(dest_hash, &source_hash, 32);
```

Note that this *only* works if the binary representations are indeed the same. If for instance, library A stores the hash in big-endian and library B stores it in little-endian, you need a more complex conversion. While in the case of hashes, it is very likely that the binary representation is indeed identical, be sure to double check that before writing a `memcpy` based conversion.

C++20 added the [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast), which can also be used for conversions like this, and will in all likelihood generate identical machine code to a solution based on calling `memcpy`. If your compiler already supports this, you may prefer `bit_cast` as it is syntactically similar to the built-in C++ casts.

Comment: As of C++20, the same logic can be expressed more nicely with [`std::bit_cast<>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast).

Comment: @underscore_d Good point about bit_cast. I will add that to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: How would I do this conversion using memcpy, could you give me an example?

Comment: @user2524707 Added an example for you.

Comment: @underscore_d `std::bit_cast` cannot be used to convert to an array because an array cannot be return type of a function.

Comment: @eerorika Fair enough, so then OP can use an `std::array` instead, which has plenty of other benefits too.

Comment: @underscore_d unless they need to serialise into a larger buffer, which in my experience is the typical case with serialisation.

Comment: @eerorika How does using `std::array` prevent serialisation? I feel like `.data()` should handle any concerns about accessing the bytes and/or avoiding possible allowance for padding, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d You serialise data into a long sequence of bytes. Typically that sequence isn't simply one integer, but something more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried out the following and that seem to have worked fine. However, I'm not sure of the possible implications.

```
uint256_t msg = 1040449494439944;
uint8_t* hash =  (uint8_t*) &msg;
cout << sizeof(hash) << endl;
```

Comment: It's only legal to reinterpret other objects as `[un[signed]] char`, and `uint8_t` is not guaranteed to be a `char` type, although in practice it usually is.

Comment: That said, please avoid old C-style casts in C++ code, and instead use the right cast for the given context, in this case (if you must, and you know it's valid) `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>`

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 we will have `std::bit_cast` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) for this. Until then the standard and defined way would be to use `std::memcpy`:

```
uint256_t msg = 1040449494439944;
uint8_t hash[32] = {};
std::memcpy(hash, &msg, sizeof(msg));
```

In depth explanation of why `c-cast` that ultimately calls `reinterpret_cast` in this case is bad by [Jason Turner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L06nbZXD2D0).